# My jquery code is not working for changing the page with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I type my first code with ajax but it doesn't.Please help.
It must be change the section content with inside of menu.txt when I click the menu button.But it doesn't work.

this is my html code:

```
<li id="navMenuButton">
              <a  href="#" onclick="$menu.txt.loadDoc();">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Menu</a>
</li>
<section id="homepage">
    <div id="main-content" class="container">  
      <div class="jumbotron">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
.
.
.
```

and this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("#homepage").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "menu.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
});
```

Comment: You don't need `#` simply write `document.getElementById("homepage").innerHTML..` .Also ,check your browser console is there any error ? Is ajax call successful ?

Comment: I am getting this error: loadDoc is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: You can change your code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qf01pde8/) then try again

Answer (score 1):

The [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler takes a function to execute **once** the DOM is loaded. It has to be an anonymous function statement or the reference to an already declared named function.

About the ajax request...Since you use jQuery, I would suggest you to try the jQuery [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // An anonymous function to pass to the ready handler

  // A named function for the ajax request
  function loadDoc(e){
    e.preventDefault()  // to prevent the normal behavior of the anchor
  
    $.ajax({
      url: "menu.txt",  // make sure the path and filename is correct
      method: "get",  // can be omited because it is the default
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response){
        $("#homepage").html(response) // the text response passed to the .html() method
      },
      error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log("Status",status,"\nERROR",error)  // If there is an error
      }
    })
  }
  
  // Click handler for the anchor child of #navMenuButton
  $("#navMenuButton a").click(loadDoc)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="navMenuButton">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
    <br class="hidden-xs"> Menu</a>
</li>
<section id="homepage"></section>
```

The demo obviously won't work here because the "menu.txt" file does not exist and because SO snippets are bloquing requests. But you can see the error callback is fired.